# PCA in Julia MultivariateStats.jl

Tags: matlab, julia, pca

I am using **PCA** in the Julia package [MultivariateStats.jl](http://multivariatestatsjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I am trying to covert an old Matlab script to Julia. However, I cannot run the Matlab script anymore. I am dealing with a series of images. First I want to make sure I got the input matrix right. I reshaped each image to a vector and put `n` images to a `m x n` matrix. I think the format of this data is correct, same as Matlab. Then I generated a PCA model by `M = fit(PCA, data)`. Matlab would return `[coeff,score,latent]`. How do I get those in Julia?

Comment: is there a compelling reason to use MultivariateStats.jl? You can easily do this with an SVD.

Comment: The reason to use MultivariateStats is that the output dimension is easy to control and I don't have to deal with the means.

Comment: by output dimension do you mean the number of PCs (= # of singular vectors?) if you want `k` PCs, with `k <= min(m,n)`, then you can use `svds` : `svds(X, nsv = k)`. alternatively, you can call `svd` and just use the first `k` singular vectors. to get the column means of your matrix `X`, you can use `mean(X, 1)`. I suspect that you do not care to save them, so when centering `X` you can simply call `Y = broadcast(-, x, mean(x, 1))` and then run `svds(Y, nsv = k)`.

Comment: Based on the way I construct the input `m x n` matrix, each column is an image vector, shouldn't I calculate `mean(X, 2)`?

Comment: oh, are your columns not the predictors (pixels)? then yes, you should center against the rows (predictor means). see updated post

Comment: I guess I am confused here. Each column is an image. So [i, j] would be the ith pixel of image j. Should I calculate means of column or row?

Comment: use row means. your other comment about Matlab then applies: `score` is `US` and `coeff` is `V`

Answer (score 5):

A PCA on a data matrix ***X*** of `m` rows and `n` predictors is merely an [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) on ***X***, defined as ***X = USV'***. You can reconstruct those three objects based on the matrices ***U***, ***S***, and ***V*** with the Julia call `U, S, V = svd(X)`.

If I understand the [MATLAB PCA documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) correctly, then

- `score` is ***U***
- `latent` is ***S***
- `coeff` is ***VS***

and one recovers the data with `X = score * coeff'`.

Note that if you call `svd` to do your PCA, then Julia's `svd` function returns `S` as a vector, whereas in Matlab `svd` returns `S` as a square matrix. When reconstructing `X` in Julia, the call is `X = U * Diagonal(S) * V'`, whereas in Matlab you can simply write `X = U * S * V'`. For `pca` in Matlab, `latent` is a vector.

Do not forget to center your matrix first. Assuming that you have sufficient memory, then `Y = broadcast(-, X, mean(X,1))` creates a centered copy of `X`. You can then run `U, S, V = svd(Y)`.

Of course, this assumes that your predictors are the **columns** of ***X***. That is how mathematicians think of it. Statisticians often put predictors as **rows** of ***X***. The PCA call in Julia assumes that the rows correspond to predictors. In that case, the ***U*** and ***V*** matrices are reversed, and one must center `X` along its rows with `Y = broadcast(-, X, mean(X,2))`.

Comment: In Julia 0.5 you should use Diagonal(S) instead of diagm(S), since diagm unnecessarily  constructs a full, dense matrix, whereas Diagonal just stores the diagonal elements.

Comment: Matlab also returns `latent` as a vector.

Comment: oops, that comment about matrix vs. vector applies to Matlab's `svd` function

Comment: Is the `S` from julia `svd` sorted from largest to smallest? Are the projections in `U` sorted?

Comment: yes, the singular values `S` are sorted from largest to smallest by default. any numerical software worth your time should do this. by extension, both `U` and `V` are "sorted" in that the the first column of each corresponds to the first (largest) singular value, the second column to the second singular value, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is more efficient to use `svdfact`, which returns `U`, `S`, and `V'`. `svd` is just a wrapper around`svdfact`. Also no transpose of `V` is needed.

Comment: Read the Matlab manual again. Now I think in Matlab `score` is `US`, `coeff` is `V`, and `latent` is actually the variance, probably `S^2`.

Comment: ah, that makes a lot of sense, assuming that MATLAB's `PCA` is like Julia's `PCA` in that the observations are the _columns_ of `X`.